# Jar file gives java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, eclipse, jar

I have an Eclipse project that runs fine when I run it in Eclipse. I have created a Jar file in Eclipse. But when I run it using the following command:

```
D:\Java\projects\fetch>java -Xss1000m -XX:-UseGCOverheadLimit -Xmx5048m -jar bin\fetch.jar
```

I get the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: info/monitorenter/cpdetector/io/ICodepageDetector
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Unknown Source)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.getMainMethod(Unknown Source)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: info.monitorenter.cpdetector.io.ICodepageDetector
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 6 more
```

The contents of the jar are:

```
com (folder)
dist (folder)
doc (folder)
lib  (folder, contains all the jars, including the cpdetector jar)
META-INF (folder)
resources (folder)
sources (folder)
.classpath (file)
.project (file)
hibernate.cfg.xml (file)
log4j.xml (file)
```

The contents of the .classpath file are:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<classpath>
<classpathentry kind="src" path="src"/>
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="D:/Java/projects/boilerpipe-master/target/boilerpipe-core-1.2.2.jar"/>
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="D:/Java/projects/boilerpipe-master/target/boilerpipe-core-1.2.2-jar-with-dependencies.jar"/>
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="lib/jsoup-1.7.2.jar"/>
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="lib/ahocorasick-1.4-SNAPSHOT-all.jar"/>
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="lib/ahocorasick-1.4-SNAPSHOT.jar"/>
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="lib/antlr-3.4-complete.jar"/>
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="lib/chardet.jar"/>
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="lib/commons-fileupload-1.2.2.jar"/>
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="lib/commons-httpclient-3.1.jar"/>
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="lib/commons-io-2.4.jar"/>
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="lib/commons-lang-2.6.jar"/>
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="lib/commons-lang3-3.1.jar"/>
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="lib/commons-validator-1.4.0.jar"/>
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="lib/horrorss-2.2.0.jar"/>
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="lib/jackson-core-2.1.4.jar"/>
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="lib/jackson-core-asl-1.9.12.jar"/>
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="lib/jackson-mapper-asl-1.9.12.jar"/>
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="lib/jdom-1.1.3.jar"/>
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="lib/jdom-2.0.4.jar"/>
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="lib/jericho-html-3.3.jar"/>
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="lib/jline.jar"/>
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="lib/joda-time-2.2.jar"/>
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="lib/lucene-analyzers-3.6.2.jar"/>
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="lib/lucene-core-3.6.2.jar"/>
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="lib/nekohtml-1.9.13.jar"/>
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="lib/rome-1.0.jar"/>
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="lib/tika-app-1.3.jar"/>
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="lib/xerces-2.9.1.jar"/>
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="lib/xstream-1.4.4.jar"/>
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="lib/hibernate-release-4.2.0.Final/envers/hibernate-envers-4.2.0.Final.jar"/>
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="lib/hibernate-release-4.2.0.Final/jpa/hibernate-entitymanager-4.2.0.Final.jar"/>
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="lib/hibernate-release-4.2.0.Final/required/antlr-2.7.7.jar"/>
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="lib/hibernate-release-4.2.0.Final/required/dom4j-1.6.1.jar"/>
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="lib/hibernate-release-4.2.0.Final/required/hibernate-commons-annotations-4.0.1.Final.jar"/>
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="lib/hibernate-release-4.2.0.Final/required/hibernate-core-4.2.0.Final.jar" sourcepath="C:/Users/Nick/.m2/repository/org/hibernate/hibernate-core/4.2.0.Final/hibernate-core-4.2.0.Final-sources.jar"/>
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="lib/hibernate-release-4.2.0.Final/required/hibernate-jpa-2.0-api-1.0.1.Final.jar"/>
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="lib/hibernate-release-4.2.0.Final/required/javassist-3.15.0-GA.jar"/>
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="lib/hibernate-release-4.2.0.Final/required/jboss-logging-3.1.0.GA.jar"/>
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="lib/hibernate-release-4.2.0.Final/required/jboss-transaction-api_1.1_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar"/>
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="lib/hibernate-release-4.2.0.Final/optional/ehcache/ehcache-core-2.4.3.jar"/>
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="lib/hibernate-release-4.2.0.Final/optional/ehcache/hibernate-ehcache-4.2.0.Final.jar"/>
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="lib/hibernate-release-4.2.0.Final/optional/ehcache/slf4j-api-1.6.1.jar"/>
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/java/tomcat6/tomcat 6.0.35/lib/mysql-connector-java-5.1.22-bin.jar"/>
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="lib/htmlcleaner-2.4.jar"/>
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="lib/freebase-java-1.0.0.jar"/>
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="lib/javax.mail.jar"/>
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="lib/opencsv-2.3.jar"/>
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="lib/google-api-client-1.14.1-beta.jar"/>
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="lib/google-http-client-1.14.1-beta.jar"/>
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="lib/json-simple-1.1.1.jar"/>
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="lib/json-smart-1.1.jar"/>
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="lib/javatuples-1.2.jar"/>
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="lib/json-path-0.8.1.jar" sourcepath="C:/Users/Nick/.m2/repository/com/jayway/jsonpath/json-path/0.8.1/json-path-0.8.1-sources.jar"/>
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="lib/json-20090211.jar"/>
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="lib/lucene-4.3.0/core/lucene-core-4.3.0.jar"/>
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="lib/lucene-4.3.0/suggest/lucene-suggest-4.3.0.jar"/>
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="lib/solr-core-4.2.1.jar"/>
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="lib/solr-solrj-4.2.1.jar"/>
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="lib/quartz-all-2.1.7.jar"/>
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="lib/simplelatlng-1.2.0.jar"/>
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="lib/obsidian.jar"/>
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="lib/CareerjetAPIClient.jar"/>
<classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER/org.eclipse.jdt.internal.debug.ui.launcher.StandardVMType/jre6"/>
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="lib/goose-2.1.22-jar-with-dependencies.jar"/>
<classpathentry kind="con" path="com.ateji.bldt.ui.ATEJILIB_CONTAINER"/>
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="lib/commons-lang-2.4.jar"/>
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="lib/commons-logging-1.0.4.jar"/>
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="lib/httpclient-4.2.3.jar"/>
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="lib/httpcore-4.2.2.jar"/>
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="lib/httpmime-4.2.3.jar"/>
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="lib/commons-codec-1.2.jar"/>
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="lib/commons-math3-3.2.jar" sourcepath="sources"/>
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="lib/guava-14.0.1.jar"/>
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="lib/cpdetector_1.0.10.jar"/>
<classpathentry kind="output" path="bin"/>
</classpath>
```

I have already googled  java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError , and have already tried a lot of stuff but none of them work. All suggestions are welcome. Thank you.

Comment: go to buildpath and export the jar file, and make sure it is selected

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to provide the classpath when you run java on the command line.

```
java -cp lib/commons-fileupload-1.2.2.jar;......
```

or you run it within eclipse (Launch Configuration) and eclipse provides the classpath for you. The .classpath file is an eclipse artifact and thus only recognized by eclipse.

Or you can use **eclipse's runnable jar export**. `Export -> Runnable Jar File`. Ensure that you selected "Extract required libraries into generated JAR" in the Library handling section of the export dialog.

Answer (score 1):

When running as a jar, you need to specify the classpath as follows:

```
java -cp libOne.jar;libTwo.jar;... -jar myJar.jar
```

Alternatively, since you did an Eclipse export, select export `Runnable Jar`.  You then have the option to `Extract required libraries into generated JAR`.  Make sure, if you do this, that the license of these libraries allow you to do this.  Then you don't need to specify the classpath.

A jar that was exported like this is easier to use.