# Get specific element from a web page source code using java in linux CLI

Tags: java, linux, eclipse, jsoup, httpconnection

I'm making an application which will get element from a source code. When I run using my eclipse it execute well but when I compile in my linux environment using CLI it's fine the jar files and when I run  the code the error is this.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/jsoup/Jsoup
    at URLget.getElement(URLget.java:70)
    at URLget.main(URLget.java:26)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jsoup.Jsoup
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    ... 2 more
```

I am so confused because in my eclipse there is no error at all.  My goal of my code is to get specific element from the source code which is seen  in the element of "td" and "p".

Please feel free to see my code below.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;

class URLget {
    private static final String USER_AGENT = "Mozilla/5.0";
    private static final String URL = "http://www.google.com";


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        URLget labaccess = new URLget();

        try {
            // System.out.println(sendGetRequest(URL));
            getElement(sendGetRequest(URL).toString()); // new code added

        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static String sendGetRequest(String urlString) throws IOException {

        URL obj = new URL(urlString);
        HttpURLConnection httpConnection = (HttpURLConnection) obj
                .openConnection();

        httpConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");

        httpConnection.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", USER_AGENT);

        int responseCode = httpConnection.getResponseCode();
        if (responseCode == 200) {

            BufferedReader responseReader = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(httpConnection.getInputStream()));

            String responseLine;
            StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();

            while ((responseLine = responseReader.readLine()) != null) {
                response.append(responseLine + "\n");
            }
            responseReader.close();

            // print result
            return response.toString();
        }
        return null;

    }

    // new code added
    public static void getElement(String sourceCode)throws FileNotFoundException, UnsupportedEncodingException {
        String fragment = sourceCode;
        ArrayList<String> ip = new ArrayList<String>();
        Document doc = Jsoup.parseBodyFragment(fragment);

        Elements elements = doc.select("td p");

        for (int i = 0; i < elements.size(); i++) {

            if (i % 10 == 2) {
                if (elements.eq(i).text().length() <= 7
                        && !elements.eq(i).text().equalsIgnoreCase("GUIS")) {
                    ip.add(elements.eq(i).text() + " : "
                            + elements.eq(i + 1).text());
                }

            }

        }

        copyFile(ip, "sprintlab171");

    }

    // end

    public static void copyFile(ArrayList<String> fileCon1, String labname)
            throws FileNotFoundException, UnsupportedEncodingException {
        PrintWriter writer1 = new PrintWriter("C:/Users/username/Desktop/"+labname+".txt", "UTF-8");
        for (int i = 0; i < fileCon1.size(); i++) {
            writer1.println("\n" + fileCon1.get(i));
        }
        writer1.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Jar file gives java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19400561/jar-file-gives-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror)

Comment: so how should I compile the said error ?